# Is it possible to add html code to a tooltip in dc js?

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have read the following blog http://www.d3noob.org/2013/08/add-line-chart-in-dcjs.html
and now understand how to add a tooltip under the data. My question is if its possible to add custom html code as a tooltip? Say something like the bellow, and make it percieve it as HTML code instead of as a string as it currently does.

```
.title(function (d) {
return "<table><tr><td>Testtext</td></tr><tr><td>Testtext</td><tr></table>";
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding we cannot do this directly using title of dc.js, as they are using text property of jQuery and text does not work on HTML. [Refer code](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/search?l=javascript&p=2&q=title)

```
 if (_chart.renderTitle())
        enter.append("title").text(dc.pluck('data',_chart.title(d.name)));
```

You can do this by using d3.tip and refer a [live example here](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) demonstrating use of HTML in tip.